# почему стили css не отображаются на странице?

Tags: html, css

код без ошибок(?), кэш чистила, но браузер вообще не видит css(использую google)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
            
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>dhuqwhkqwhk</h1>
      <hr>
    </body>
 </html>
    css:
    h1{color:greenyellow}
```

Comment: так у вас ссылка на файл стилей не прописана же

Comment: точно, забыла об этом вообще, спасибо за ответ!